# django standalone script import error

Tags: django

I have a working django site and I'm trying to run a standalone script over its data. I am following [this](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) article, but can't get it to work. I have tried two approaches:

1)

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..'))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from mysite.main.models import Image
#from main.models import Image #should work too
```

2)

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..'))

from django.core.management import setup_environ 
from mysite import settings
#import settings #should work too
setup_environ(settings)

from mysite.main.models import Image
```

Both gives me "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'models'" raised from the module I am trying to import (main.models).

The script itself is located in the project root of a working site, with the "main" app properly installed and working. There should be no problem with settings or models.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with a very similar error myself and this snippet from Django shell code (shell.py) did it for me:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_models
loaded_models = get_models()
```

Put it before your model class import.

Comment: I have a circular model import problem since upgrading to 1.5. This fixes it, but does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why your `import` statement should not work. Make sure that the module structure matches the `import` command. The module path should be `mysite -> main -> models`. Some developers add an extra `apps` module in a project such that the path becomes `mysite -> apps -> main -> models`. Ensure that this is not the case for you.

To check, do the following from the [Django shell](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#shell) as well as the Python REPL.

```
from mysite.main.models import Image
```

If this doesn't work you'll need to troubleshoot your module structure.

Comment: thanks, I tried "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/projectpath/; export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings; django-admin.py shell" and the import did work! I am confused, any idea?

Comment: OK, this is literally killing me. Since the AttributeError is rised from "main.models" module from the "class Image(imagekit.models.ImageModel):" class definition, I tried to change the imagekit module import THERE from this: "import imagekit" to verbose: "from mysite.apps.imagekit.models import ImageModel" and guess what, now it works. Big Fat Questionmark???

Comment: Ah. For `import imagekit; imagekit.models.ImageModel` to work `imagekit` should be in your `PYTHONPATH`. I suspect it was not. However `from mysite.apps.imagekit.models import ImageModel` will work since `mysite` is in your `PYTHONPATH`. To test this add the location of `imagekit` to `PYTHONPATH` and try the first variant of import again.

Comment: But... the import from django shell succeeded with only project path in `PYTHONPATH` (see above). There are other apps in the app directory (all except main) that are successfully imported, I insert the path in `settings.py`. `from imagekit.models import ImageModel` also works. I suspect there's some magic going on in imagekit, I didn't inspect their code.

Answer (score 0):

Just clone your manage.py file. Drop the last two lines line and append your code to the end. Works like a charm! For example mine now contains the following, which outputs data from one of my database items,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "conf.settings_dev")
  #from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  #execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  from events.models import Event
  e = Event.objects.get(id="testID")
  print e.eventTitle
```

I suspect there might be a more official (and convoluted) way to do things but this is a good place to start in the meantime.